# Downloading a pdf file of larger size(like 30Mb) fails

Tags: codenameone

I have used CN1CircleProgress library while downloading pdf files. It works great if the pdf file is small. But for larger pdf files eg 30 Mb, the circle fills to 100% 2-3 times very quickly and then again it starts to download to 20-30% & download stops. The file downloaded is currupted & cannot be opened in pdf viewer. I have checked it in iOS & android devices. In simulator it just downloads to certain percent, then it stops

```
downloadPdfButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
    pdfUrlSelected = "http://roundtablenepal.org.np/uploadEpubs/57cbcc4e76258.pdf";
    pdfFileNameIdSelected = currentPdfSelected.get("magazine_title");

    filename = dir + sep;
    filename = filename + pdfFileNameIdSelected + ".pdf";
    FileSystemStorage.getInstance().mkdir(dir);
    Slider downloadSlider = new Slider();
    if (!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filename)) {
        downloadPdfFromUrl(f, pdfUrlSelected, filename, true, downloadSlider, findCancelDownload(f));
    }
});

private boolean downloadPdfFromUrl(Form f, String url, final String fileName, boolean storage, final Slider slider, Button cancel) {
    crPdf = new ConnectionRequest();
    crPdf.resume();
    crPdf.setPost(false);
    crPdf.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    crPdf.setFailSilently(true);
    crPdf.setUrl(url);
    crPdf.setTimeout(15000);
    crPdf.setDestinationFile(fileName);

    final CircleFilledProgress p = new CircleFilledProgress();
    p.setProgress(0);


    f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, p);

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addProgressListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (evt instanceof NetworkEvent) {
                NetworkEvent e = (NetworkEvent) evt;
                if (e.getProgressPercentage() >= 0) {
                    slider.setText(e.getProgressPercentage() + "%");
                    slider.setProgress(e.getProgressPercentage());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    slider.addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            p.setProgress(index);
        }
    });

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(crPdf);

    cancel.addActionListener((e) -> {
        crPdf.kill();
    });

    return crPdf.getResponseCode() == 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening the network monitor, I'm guessing you are getting a redirect which updates the progress then the redirect leads to an error page for some reason.